# Присвоить переменной значение get из адресной строки

Tags: jquery

Всем привет.

Есть юрл с параметрами, например `/page.php?fbfb=y&komplektn=3`
Как в скрипте jquery присвоить переменной значение get параметра?

Что-то типо такого: `var fbfb = <?=$_REQUEST['fbfb']?>;`

Comment: jQuery напрямую доступ к GET параметрам не имеет, т к работает на клиенте. Можно сервером формировать строку с переменными в JSON например, а в jquery распарсивать её. Или тупо присвоить какому нибудь элементу на странице GET параметр

Comment: Ясно. Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[(jQuery) URL Parser v2.2](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser)

> An AMD compatible utility to parse urls and provide easy access to their attributes (such as the protocol, host, port etc), path segments, querystring parameters, fragment parameters and more.
> The core parser functionality is based on the Regex URI parser by Steven Levithan, and the query string parsing is handled by a modified version of node-querystring.

Comment: И я поделюсь своим великом: http://bars.koding.com/test/hash-get-params/

Основа лежит в http://bars.koding.com/test/hash-get-params/hash-get-params.js

Это для оперирования с «ajax-овыми» ссылками вида http://some.com/#!?foo=bar&other=42 , но несложно перелепить и для оперирования с реальными query-данными. Умеет парсить "item[one]=1&item[two]=2" в `{ 'one': '1', 'two': '2' }`;

Доставать так:

 var foo = GET('foo'); // "bar"
 var item_one = GET('item[one]'); // "1"
 var items = GET('item'); // { ... }

Менять/добавлять так:

 GET('foo', 'new'); // теперь #!?foo=new&other=42

и т. д.